# Erlang register process

Tags: erlang

I try to spawn new process and register it:

```
-module(db).

-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    register( db , spawn( db, abs, [-100])).
```

But when i try in erlang shell:

1> db:start().

I see:

*true
(emacs@myhost)2> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 1-Dec-2010::17:42:27 ===
Error in process <0.112.0> on node 'emacs@myhost' with exit value: {undef,[{db,abs,[-100]}]}*

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because `db:abs/1` is not defined.

Comment: abs it's function from erlang module.

Comment: Are all the features that I want to make a separate process should be export? If yes, then how can i spawn function from erlang module for example?

Comment: Then your code should read spawn(erlang, abs, [-100]). See the documentation for spawn/3 at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3

Comment: (It doesn't really make sense that you would want to do this in a real project, but we'll just ignore that :)

Comment: All functions that you wish to spawn must be exported from a module. All the erlang BIFs are exported from the module `erlang`.